# CustomCell in UITableView in objective c

Tags: ios, uitableview, xcode6

[image]

I have attached a sample output here .... It  has two cells first one is having functioncode,starttime,endtime and second one  has break time.

Now want i want to do is third one should contain functionCode:,starttime:,endtime:,

My array has 3 dictionary

```
(
        {
        date = "2016-01-20";
        "end_time" = "11:10:00";
        "function_code" = RCV;
        "operator_id" = JOHN;
        "start_time" = "11:00:00";
        "total_time" = 10;
        "total_units" = 19;
    },
        {
        "break_time" = 65;
    },
        {
        date = "2016-01-20";
        "end_time" = "12:25:00";
        "function_code" = PIK;
        "operator_id" = JOHN;
        "start_time" = "12:15:00";
        "total_time" = 10;
        "total_units" = 26;
    } )
```

This is my cellforrow at indexpath  method

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {

   if (indexPath.row ==0)
    {

        self.tempDictionary = [self.arrData1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        NSLog(@"The dictionary contains:%@",self.tempDictionary);


        static NSString *CellIndentifier =@"TableViewCell";
        TableViewCell *cell =[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIndentifier];

        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[TableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIndentifier];

       }

        NSLog(@" the dictionary contains all :%@",self.tempDictionary);


        NSString *strFunctionCodeValue =[self.tempDictionary objectForKey:@"function_code"];
        NSString *strStartTimeValue = [self.tempDictionary objectForKey:@"start_time"];
        NSString *strEndTimeValue = [self.tempDictionary objectForKey:@"end_time"];
        NSString *strTotalUnitsValue =[self.tempDictionary objectForKey:@"total_units"];
        NSString *strTotalTimeValue = [self.tempDictionary objectForKey:@"total_time"];


        cell.lblFunctionCodeValue.text = strFunctionCodeValue;
        cell.lblStartTimeValue.text = strStartTimeValue;
        cell.lblEndTimeValue.text = strEndTimeValue;
        cell.lblTotalUnitsValue.text =strTotalUnitsValue;
        cell.lblTotalTimeValue.text = strTotalTimeValue;

        return cell;

    }
    else
    {

        static NSString *cellIdentifier1 =@"TableViewCell1";
        self.tempDictionary = [self.arrData1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        NSLog(@" dicitionary :%@",self.tempDictionary);

        TableViewCell1 *cell1 =(TableViewCell1 *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier1];
        if (cell1 == nil) {
            cell1 =[[TableViewCell1 alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier1];

      }

        NSString *breakTimeValue = [self.tempDictionary objectForKey:@"break_time"];
        cell1.lblBreakTimeValue.text = breakTimeValue;

        return cell1;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a class named **MyObject** inherit from NSObject. It will contain the following properties 
date, end_time, function_code, operator_id, start_time, total_time, total_units.

Then you will make another class **MyObject2** containing only one property ** break_time**.

You will parse your dictionary into respective models by adding a check if allkeys on dictionary is greater than 1 it means you have to parse your data in myObject1 otherwise you will parse it into myObject2. You will be adding these parsed objects in your array which can further be used as a datasource for uitableview. Now in delegate method of tableview cellForRowAtIndexPath, all you need is to implement a check.

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

     id *object = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
     if([object isKindOfClass:MyObject]){
         CustomCell1 *cell1 = (CustomCell1 *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CustomCell1"];
         return cell1;
     }else{
        CustomCell2 *cell2 = (CustomCell2 *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CustomCell2"];
         return cell2;
     }
     return;
}
```

On your existing code you can add a check.

```
self.tempDictionary = [self.arrData1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
if([[self.tempDictionary allKeys] count]>1){
         static NSString *CellIndentifier =@"TableViewCell";
    TableViewCell *cell =[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIndentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[TableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIndentifier];

    }

    NSLog(@" the dictionary contains all :%@",self.tempDictionary);

    NSString *strFunctionCodeValue =[self.tempDictionary objectForKey:@"function_code"];
    NSString *strStartTimeValue = [self.tempDictionary objectForKey:@"start_time"];
    NSString *strEndTimeValue = [self.tempDictionary objectForKey:@"end_time"];
    NSString *strTotalUnitsValue =[self.tempDictionary objectForKey:@"total_units"];
    NSString *strTotalTimeValue = [self.tempDictionary objectForKey:@"total_time"];


    cell.lblFunctionCodeValue.text = strFunctionCodeValue;
    cell.lblStartTimeValue.text = strStartTimeValue;
    cell.lblEndTimeValue.text = strEndTimeValue;
    cell.lblTotalUnitsValue.text =strTotalUnitsValue;
    cell.lblTotalTimeValue.text = strTotalTimeValue;


}else{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier1 =@"TableViewCell1";
    self.tempDictionary = [self.arrData1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@" dicitionary :%@",self.tempDictionary);

    TableViewCell1 *cell1 =(TableViewCell1 *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier1];
    if (cell1 == nil) {
        cell1 =[[TableViewCell1 alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier1];

 }


    NSString *breakTimeValue = [self.tempDictionary objectForKey:@"break_time"];

    cell1.lblBreakTimeValue.text = breakTimeValue;


    return cell1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @shehzad Ali,i got the error like control may reach end of non-void function ,

Comment: return nil at the end of the function.

Comment: ya i used return nil at the end of the function ,app got crash ."NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:" this is the error

Comment: Thanks @Shehzad Ali ,now i got the result, i return the cell over there .once again thanks for ur help

Answer (score 0):

What is the question?

Probably you need to build 2 different cells, and depending on some data, you return one or another in cellForRow.

Comment: thanks @Ricardo ,i want to build 2 different cells please help me to do that ,

Comment: Just add two cells in the storyboard and assign them 2 different subclasses, each one with different outlets. Dont forget to use 2 different cellIdentifiers (for instance use the class name).

Comment: And in code return the one you want for a specific row. In cellForRow

Comment: @ChandrikaVisvesh check the second part of the code updated by me